# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null Parameter type objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use stored procedures in Entity Framework Core. When executing a stored procedure, I am passing two input parameters and one output parameter. I keep getting this error:

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.

This is my code:

```
public string InsertCardsData(DateTime RecordingStartDate, DateTime RecordingEndDate)
{
        try
        {
            // DateTime DRecEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(RecordingEndDate);
            DateTime DRecEndDate = RecordingEndDate.AddDays(1);

            var RecordStartDate = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "RecordingStartDate",
                Value = RecordingStartDate,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            };

            var RecordEndDate = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "RecordingEndDate",
                Value = DRecEndDate,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            };

            var RecordCount = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "RecLoadCount",
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };

            var SQL = "Exec Recload_InsertPrimeExtract @RecordingStartDate, @RecordingEndDate, @RecLoadCount OUT";
            var result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(SQL, RecordStartDate, RecordEndDate, RecordCount);
            var RecordCountValue = RecordCount.Value.ToString();

            return RecordCountValue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
}
```

I will put a a meaningful catch statement, but right now, I am putting a breakpoints in catch statement and the above error occurs.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not your issues, but why are you doing this `DateTime DRecEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(RecordingEndDate)` you are converting a datetime to a datetime ? Also why are you returning a string for a count which is obviously numeric

Comment: sorry, I fixed the above code. I was passing string before and then I changed to DateTime.

Comment: Are you declaring `using System.Data.SqlClient` or `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;`?

Comment: Try breaking it down to an [mcve].  Where are your using statements?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely your issues is caused due to a [breaking change in EF Core 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#fromsql), by declaring `using 
 System.Data.SqlClient` when it should be`using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

**Why**

> `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` is the flagship data access driver for SQL
>   Server going forward, and `System.Data.SqlClient` no longer be the focus
>   of development. Some important features, such as Always Encrypted, are
>   only available on `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

**Further More**

> If your code takes a direct dependency on `System.Data.SqlClient`, you
>   must change it to reference `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead; as the
>   two packages maintain a very high degree of API compatibility, this
>   should only be a simple package and namespace change.

**Related issues on github**

- https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18218
- https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16812

Comment: I was using System.Data.SQLClient. As soon as I changed to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, my code started working.