# Stored Procedure Returning Data Set Under .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Using Entity Framework 6.3, I am trying to execute a stored procedure that returns a dataset (as a result of a `select` statement in the procedure, that joins multiple tables). The stored procedure exists and I am able to execute it via SSMS using the same credentials, just to eliminate the obvious suggestions.

The call to the stored procedure looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient; //!

var timestamp = new DateTime.UtcNow();
var scheduleNo = "123";
var machine = "3";

var result = await DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ScheduleData>(
    "exec GetScheduleData @UpdateTimeStamp, @ScheduleNo, @Machine",
        new SqlParameter("@UpdateTimeStamp", timestamp),
        new SqlParameter("@ScheduleNo", scheduleNo),
        new SqlParameter("@Machine", machine))
    .ToListAsync();
```

The execution fails with the following error:

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.

I searched for this exact error, found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705767/sqlparametercollection-only-accepts-non-null-sqlparameter-type-objects-not-str), but I don't think it's applicable, as the original poster doesn't even use EF.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859695/the-sqlparametercollection-only-accepts-non-null-parameter-type-objects) doesn't seem applicable, as I am already using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` (as emphasized in the listing above).

There is no `DbSet` defined in the `DbContext` that would correspond to the result set being returned from the procedure, so I can't really use `DBSet<ScheduleData>.FromSql` or `.FromSqlRaw`.

FWIW, I need the result set to be readonly, so don't need EF change tracking, etc.

Is there a way to do it without completely bypassing EF and having to create a separate DB connection?

Comment: I don't think that's the correct `using` for EF 6. I think Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is for EF Core. Have you tried System.Data.SqlClient instead?

Comment: @Crowcoder: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` should work for _both_ .NET Core _and_ .NET Framework. In fact, its entire purpose is to [unify the code base between both platforms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/). (Though, of course, it should be `SqlClient` not `SqlCLient`; I assume that's a typo here.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney Yes, a typo. Fixed.

Comment: The code makes no sense. ".ToListAsync() ?? new List<ScheduleData>();" - ToListAsync has to be awaited and NEVER returns null.. If no object is insected, the list is empty, but it is there.

Comment: I'm able to recreate the issue myself. Looking at EF6 source code, it has System.Data references everywhere. Humor me and qualify your parameters with `System.Data.SqlClient` so that they do not resolve to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Microsoft.Data is not quite a drop in replacement for existing code as described in the link you posted: "*...update any using references or qualified references.*"

Comment: @TomTom You are right. That's a remnant from something else I was trying. Removing the ??.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yup, you got it. I was under the impression that `Sql.Data.SqlClient` was deprecated... It is, but not if one is still using EF6 like I am. Thank you!

Comment: @Crowcoder If you would like to formulate your comments as an actual answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Well, yes, _of course_ the namespaces need to be updated. But the OP was already using it, so the namespaces are already established. Again, the point is that the library is _supposed_ to work with both Framework _and_ Core. A bit disappointed to learn that it doesn't work with EF6.

Comment: @JeremyCaney my point is if EF6 is looking for System.Data it doesn't matter what *your* code is using. If you like, you can fork the EF6 repository and update it to use Microsoft.Data.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Ah, yes! Good point. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension method from [B3.Extensions.Data](https://github.com/bayramucuncu/B3.Extensions.Data). Any kind of raw sql query can execute using entity framework like following..

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
   var sql = "SELECT type, SUM(length) FROM ways GROUP BY type";
   var queryResult = await _context.ExecuteQueryAsync(sql);

   return Ok(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue and in my scenario using .NET Core 3.1 with EF6 I had to qualify the parameters as Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.

```
command.Parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@param1", someString));
```

Kind of the opposite of the comments suggestion, at least as I read it.